# Change the Appearance of a Summary Link Web Part Tool Part

Tags: 2013, web-part

How can I make my Summary Link Web Part Tool Part look like the example given below?

My current State:

[image]

How I want it to be:

[image]

Important is only the layout not the content.

Answer (score 1):

Like `Content Query Web Part` , the `Summary Link Web Part` has an `XSL file` as Item Style that can be customized to show it with your custom themes and style.

To open it.

> Go to the Root Site > Style Library > XSL Style Sheets > `SummaryLinkMain.xsl`.

To customize your Summary task style you can check the following links

- [Customizing-styles-of-summary-links-web](http://surendratech.blogspot.com/2013/06/customizing-styles-of-summary-links-web.html)
- [Create a CustomItemStyle](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/CustomItemStyle/)

**Note :** you should take a backup from `SummaryLinkMain.xsl` before update it to allow rollback. also, you can ask your SharePoint Designer to help you with this kind of customization.